# Simulate next button click with knockoutjs and durandal

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, durandal

I'm trying to simulate Jquery click  in KnockoutJS without much success.

Script :

```
showMessage = function () {
    app.showMessage(
        " möchten Sie fortfahren?", //text
        "BESTAETIGUNG", //title
        ['Ja', 'Nein'] //options
    ).then(function (result) {
        if (result == "Ja") {
            toastr.success("Sie werden weitergeleitet");
            toastr.info('Ja'); //call toastr for notification
            $("#anfrageSubMenu li.active").removeClass("active").next("li").click();
            //.addClass("active");//.trigger('click');
        }
        if (result == "Nein") {
            toastr.error("Bitte Pruefen Sie Ihre Eingaben");
            toastr.info('Nein');
        }
    }).fail(function (result) {

    });
}
```

If i remove click and replace it with `addClass("active")` this will work.

Comment: I think you must just remove .click()  and replace it with trigger('click'); This should cause all event listeners to be called.

Comment: it doesn't work  thats why i made it as comment

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you are trying to fire an event on click, the `click` binding in knockout will likely be easier to use.

Comment: and how do you add the click binding in a modal message on a random element ?

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
$("#anfrageSubMenu li.active").removeClass("active").next("li").trigger("click");
```

will only work if you actually have a 'click' event bound to the element you're triggering it for (in your case, the next `<li/>` element after the `.active` one). How are you binding events to your view? Are you using knockout bindings, jQuery, or something else?

Comment: i'm using knockout click binding